# jQuery UI Sortable, how to fix the list height?

Tags: jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using jQuery UI "sortable" plugin to be able to select and sort items.

I set up the plugin to have two lists, one for "available" items, the second for "selected" items.

The plugin works as expected, I can move items from one list to the other.

However, when I remove one item from the list, the height of the list is lowered. Is there any way to fix it?

In fact, i'd like to set the outer border of both list to the initial height of the left items (at the beginning, all items are in the first list)

This picture describe what I want to do[image]:

The red lines are what I'd like. I want both lists to have this size, fixed.

Here is my code (generated from an asp.net webpage actually) :

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#sourceItems").sortable({
            connectWith: "#targetItems",
            update: function (event, ui) {
                $("#selectedUserIDs").val(
                    $("#targetItems").sortable('toArray')
                    );
            },
            placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
        });
        $("#targetItems").sortable({
            connectWith: "#sourceItems",
            placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
        });

        $("#sourceItems, #targetItems").disableSelection();
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#sourceItems, #targetItems { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-right: 10px; background: #eee; padding: 5px; width: 230px; border:solid 1px black; }
#sourceItems li, #targetItems li { margin: 5px; padding: 5px; width: 200px; height: 12px; }
</style>
<div style="float: left; display: inline-block; width:fill-available">
    <p>Available :</p>
    <ul id="sourceItems" class="droptrue">
        <li class="ui-state-default" id='i1'>item1</li>        
        <li class="ui-state-default" id='i32'>item2</li>        
        <li class="ui-state-default" id='i47'>item3</li>        
        <li class="ui-state-default" id='i46'>item4</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div style="float: left; display: inline-block;">
    <p>Selected :</p>
    <ul id="targetItems" class="droptrue">
    </ul>
</div>
<div style="display: none">
    <input name="selectedUserIDs" type="text" id="selectedUserIDs" />
</div>
```

The hidden input field is my container for storing selected items (posted with the form).

I've tried by adding `.height($("#sourceItems).outerHeight());` to *both* lists, but this does not works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#targetItems").height($("#sourceItems").height());
    $("#sourceItems").height($("#sourceItems").height());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JEY4U/1/

**Old Answer:**

Use a 'helper' function, which makes sure the dragged elements have proper width and height.
Something like this:

```
helper: function(event, ui) {
    $(ui).width($(ui).width());
    $(ui).height($(ui).height());
    ui.children().each(function() {
        $(this).width($(this).width());
    });
    return ui;
}
```

You use it like this:

```
$(SOME_OBJECT).sortable({
    connectWith: ...,
    placeholder: ...,
    ......
    helper: function....
});
```

Of course you can write any costume helper function you'd like.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, in the css rules, the `<li>` have explictly `height: 12px;`.

Comment: The 'sortable' widget uses the helper function as a "proxy" for displaying the dragged element, while the dragging occurs. There might be a change to the element's style while it's being dragged, and this is where the 'helper' function comes in handy.

Comment: I try to add your helper function, but there is no difference. I checked using IE dev tools, height is always set to 12px in the style.

Comment: I thought you had a problem with the size of the dragged <li> elements, but now I see that your intention is to make the <ul> elements the same height. take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JEY4U/  Is that what you mean? Here I just set a height of 300px to both lists.

Comment: I don't know in advance the size of the list. In fact, I want to stick the height of both lists to the initial size of the first list (all items are in the first list when the page has loaded).

Comment: hum.... your code, on jsfiddle works as expected. But when I apply it to my code, it does not works. I can see, however, that the height is set to 0px. Is there anything that can cause `.height()` to return 0, instead of the actual dimensions ?

Comment: Do you put it inside `$(document).ready(function(){});`? This makes sure that you check for the size only when all the DOM elements are loaded and ready.

Comment: yes, actually the shorter syntax `$(function() { }`, but I did

Comment: Ok, I find the solution. My lists was behind a tab (created with jqueryUI tabs widget). That's why my height was 0px. To resolve the issue, I move the setup of the sortable widget before the setup of the tabs (the short when the list is still visible). Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3):

I came here looking for a similar, but more generalized solution to the same problem.  The solution here didn't help me, but I figured it out on my own and thought it might be helpful to share it.

I didn't want the two sortable lists to be fixed, I just wanted them to stay the same height.  When you are dealing with a large number of items, having two dynamically sized boxes around the list can make it hard to work with, as the one box is so much smaller than the other.  Making both boxes a fixed height is also less than optimal, as then you end up with scrollbars once your number of items in one list exceeds that height.  I wanted both boxes to dynamically expand using the built-in functionality of the JQuery sortable, connectWith code, but I also wanted them to both just be set to the larger of the two.  To do this I found that you can modify the padding on the lists, and that area will still be an interactable area for purposes of drag-and-drop.

So, to make two connectWith, sortable lists keep the same height, you can add the following handler for the over event:

```
        over: function(event, ui) {
           var heightDiff = $("#sourceItems").height() - $("#targetItems").height();
           $("#sourceItems").css('padding-bottom', (Math.abs(heightDiff) - heightDiff) / 2 + 'px');
           $("#targetItems").css('padding-bottom', (Math.abs(heightDiff) + heightDiff) / 2 + 'px');
        }
```

Here's a fiddler example extending the other example with this event handler: http://jsfiddle.net/TLrn7/

Comment: I really like this solution, I tried setting the height for *over* or *stop* events before but that didn't work out as expected. This however works great!

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery UI list height is set to a specific height using CSS. Example for 300px height.

```
.ui-autocomplete {
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
/* IE 6 doesn't support max-height
 * we use height instead, but this forces the menu to always be this tall
 */
* html .ui-autocomplete {
  height: 300px;
}
```

Read the documentation here: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#maxheight